# Grunt and the current directory

Tags: less, gruntjs

How do I specify current directory in grunfile.js?

It looks like, all paths in the grunt tasks are relative to the grunt's file location.

My intention is to be able to run a grunt task in any project's subfolder, having that I don't know file name.

Let me clarify, for example, I have 50 folders with components, inside some folder I have 2 *.less files. What I want is to be able to run the lesscss grant task inside that particular folder, which converts those *.less files to *.css (preserving the original names).

Comment: Having to manually go to a particular location and run each step kinda goes against the whole idea of Grunt which is to automate your project as a whole. 

Are you really asking, "How can I have Grunt compile less files into css with file name matching the directory it is in?"

Answer (score 1):

In my project `grunt-jscs-checker`, we do it this way for the tests:

```
grunt.file.setBase( "test" );
```

[Code](https://github.com/gustavohenke/grunt-jscs-checker/blob/37c73ef2c2a2bde0478e8ce0a3289bacc5864343/test/test.js#L5)